# How to handle setOnPageChangeListener() in fragment tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

In my application I have three **fragment tabs** similar to the [this screen](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/761642-android-app-development-for-beginners-navigation-with-tabs). Also I have a main activity other than these three tabs. My problem is when the application starts, it is already selected the first tab and always display the fragment related to it.

But I need to display main activity when the application starts and if the user selects only display the relevant fragment. How to handle this situation? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

This is the tab fragment code sample: **MainActivity.java**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainActivity);
    viewPager=(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.fragment);
    actionBar=getActionBar();
    mAdapter=new TabPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    for(String tabName: tabs){            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabName).setTabListener(this));
    }
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2){

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

                    }
                });

 }
```

**EDIT**

**Manifest file**

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Here tab fragments are also in my main activity. Also main activity has its own layout. I added LAUNCHER activity as above in manifest file. What is happening here is when the application launch that tab fragment layout (first one)display always without MainActivity layout. I need to display these tab fragments only if the use selected them.

Comment: Have you made changes in your manifest file?

Comment: No I did not change anything in manifest for this.

Comment: Register activity you want to start on app start as a launcher activity and after that this fragment activity. And from main activity start this tabs activity.

Comment: Post your manifest file. And also write the names of activities in your question.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh I updated my question with manifest file segment and explain bit more there. I already added android.intent.category.LAUNCHER to manifest file. The problem is my tab fragments also place in the same activity.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with fragments, finally I could find out a solution. I'm doubt is there any better solution for this. If there is any feel free to update here. Hope this will help for someone who face the same issue.

The problem occur because, though I define `LAUNCHER` activity in manifest, same activity contains the fragment tabs. So always default tab is selected and because of this reason always fragment layout visible and cannot see activity layout. So what I did is, in `xml of ViewPager` set to gone.

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Then in my activity I created a variable to detect whether the app start for the first time and the user still not selected any tab.

```
 boolean isStart=true;
```

Then in `onTabSelected()` method checked  `isStart=false` means the tab is selected by the user. Then I set the `viewPager to VISIBLE`.

Comment: Hey Thank you for the support. I used above way to do it. I don't know is there any other better way to do it. If you have any solution let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

In `MainActivity` create your main display that open when your app start. And in `MainActivity` create button to strat other activity that contains fragment tabs. And register this new activity in manifest file. If user interested to go on tabs activity in that case he opens that otherwise not.

Comment: It is impossible to change the design. Tab Fragments should be in main activity.

Comment: Ok then create one xml and activity for staring screen and register that activity as launcher activity and provide one button in taht activity to start MainActivity.